# Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.44 differs from your MySQL server version 10.0.20. This may cause unpredictable behavior

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin

How can I fix this "error" in phpmyadmin ? Is this a serious problem, I should care about?

- Server Version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-1~trusty-log - mariadb.org binary
- distribution Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql 5.5.44
- PHP-Erweiterung: mysqli Dokumentation
- All packages are uptodate (official ubuntu 14.04 repos)
- On MariaDB I use the official repos from mariadb.org

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That really depends on how much you trust MariaDB to be a perfect drop in replacement for MySQL. Don't they provide their own client libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed the problem:

```
apt-get remove php5-mysql
apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

I had to reinstall phpmyadmin, the errors disappeared now.